# JS Promise intended to resolve or reject randomly, displays 'undefined' in then/catch for the random value passed as argument in resolve/reject

Tags: javascript, promise, backend, resolve, winjs-promise

Qn. Create a JavaScript Promise that, after a delay of 2 seconds, either resolves with the message "Hello World" or rejects with the error message "Error occurred". The outcome (resolve or reject) should be determined by a random condition, ensuring a 50/50 chance of either occurring each time the code runs.

Solution Code has been given in description. However, I have tried to pass the random value based on which the resolution/ rejection takes place, but that value is displayed as undefined in then and catch parts of the code.

```
const Promises = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
{
    let ch = Math. Random()>0.5;
    setTimeout(() => 
    {
      if(ch)
      resolve("Hello World",ch);
      else 
      reject("Error Occurred!!!",ch);
      },2000);
    });

    Promises.then((msg,ch) => 
    {
      console.log(msg);
      console.log(ch);
    }).catch((msg,ch)=>
    {
       console.log(msg);
       console.log(ch);
    });
```

**Output 1**

```
    Hello World
    undefined
```

**Output 2**

```
    Error Occurred !!!
    undefined
```

Comment: Promises only resolve or reject with a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Promise return single value(can be anything like string, array or objects etc) just like normal function.

Comment: Than how to pass the choice as desired in the answer.

Comment: Pass it *instead* of the message, or pass an object consisting of message and random value.